# How to get count of images stored in SD card

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I need to calculate the number of images stored in SD card and so i would like to name the images unique like Sample0,Sample1,Sample2,Sample3,etc.
Is it Possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It gives the number of images present in the images folder of your SD card:

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/images");
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        int numberOfImages=files.length;
```

Comment: any time.. you can use filterfiles to restrict file type

Comment: cant understand.Why we need to Restrict file type

Answer (score 1):

I now it's been a long time, but, the method above would give you the number of any kind of files and directories within images folder, not only the images number, and doesn't look for images in subfolders inside the images directory.

Let's say we have this structure:

```
Images/
 - img1.jpg
 - img2.jpg
 - data.dat
 - whatever.pdf
 - Folder/
    - img3.png
```

The method above will give you 5 and you should obtain 3 isn't it?

I've been working on something similar and I'm pretty sure there is a more efficient way, but with this method I get the number of all images within the SDCard, or any given directory and its subfolders...

Here we go:

```
public int countImgs(File file, int number) {
        File[] dirs = file.listFiles();
        String name = "";
        if (dirs != null) { // Sanity check
            for (File dir : dirs) {
                if (dir.isFile()) { // Check file or directory
                    name = dir.getName().toLowerCase();
                    // Add or delete extensions as needed
                    if (name.endsWith(".png") || name.endsWith(".jpg")
                            || name.endsWith(".jpeg")) {
                        number++;
                    }
                } else number = countImgs(dir, number);
            }
        }

        return number;
}
```

Where the param file is the root directory and the number would be 0 at start. So to use it:

```
int imgNumber = countImgs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

it will be an error when files = null when get the count of images stored in SD card

```
     File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/images");
     File[] files = dir.listFiles();
     String strnumberOfImages=files.length;
     int intnumberOfImages= 0;
     try{
          intnumberOfImages = Integer.parseInt( strnumberOfImages);
     }catch ( Exception e ){
          intnumberOfImages = 0;
     }
```

if just check empty or not

```
    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/images");
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    
if(files != null){
      // there are picz                     
}else{
      // sd card empty
}
```